# Unreasonably high ping on Mac

Tags: network, wifi, ping

Here's my hardware setup :

```
ADSL Line in --> TP-Link TD-8840T Modem --[LAN Cable]--> TP-Link TL-WR1043ND Router.
```

I'm connected to the TL-WR1043ND via WiFi, and here are my pings :

Ping to modem

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=568.727 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=538.867 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1016.813 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1199.988 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=441.743 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=769.507 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=687.576 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=1152.333 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=737.375 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=63 time=611.003 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=63 time=593.407 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=63 time=537.520 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=63 time=705.519 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=63 time=561.918 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=63 time=289.272 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=63 time=240.911 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=63 time=300.519 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=63 time=474.792 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=63 time=206.313 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=63 time=195.544 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=63 time=377.278 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=63 time=528.373 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
23 packets transmitted, 22 packets received, 4.3% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 195.544/578.877/1199.988/272.600 ms
```

Ping to router

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=266.906 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=446.314 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=632.165 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=711.540 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=892.875 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=501.928 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=513.864 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=642.139 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=468.121 ms
 64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=454.529 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=240.409 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 240.409/524.617/892.875/180.400 ms
```

What could be causing this ? I'm sitting 5 meters away from the access point.

Comment: Any number of things could be bad in that "chain" including your wireless adapter.  If you connect to another network, does your wifi ping that router with expected speed?

Comment: do the same but on another device, as allan said, there are so many reasons for this. try deleting your device from the router, and starting anew, then try your ping again. Sorted the same issue with me, on my BT HH5.